# How to add new sidebar widget area to child theme?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, child-theme

I want to create a new sidebar widget area in the header of my child theme. What would be the best way to do this?

Here is the code for one of the sidebars in the parent theme:

```
<?php
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'ci_widgets_init' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'ci_widgets_init' ) ) :
    function ci_widgets_init() {
        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => __( 'Blog Sidebar', 'ci_theme'),
            'id'            => 'blog-sidebar',
            'description'   => __( 'The list of widgets assigned here will appear in your blog posts.', 'ci_theme'),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s group">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title"><span>',
            'after_title'   => '</span></h3>',
        ) );
    }
```

Can I just change the `name`, `id` and `description`, and put it in my child theme's `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is what worked for me. In my `functions.php` file I put the following code:

```
function header_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(

    'name' => 'Header Sidebar',

    'id' => 'header_sidebar',

    'before_widget' => '<aside class="widget %2$s">',

    'after_widget' => '</aside>',

    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',

    'after_title' => '</h2>',

) );

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'header_widgets_init' );
```

...and in my `header.php` file I used:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('header_sidebar') ) : endif; ?>
```

Comment: Or instead of `<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('header_sidebar') ) : endif; ?>` should I use `<?php dynamic_sidebar('header-sidebar'); ?>`? I tried both and both work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, adding the widget directly in the child theme functions.php file is perfectly acceptable.

Some parent themes provide recommendations on how best to add new functionality within child themes (helpers, classes, specific design patterns, etc.) so the ideal approach may vary from one theme to the next.

I'm happy to elaborate if you can provide any additional information about your setup.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The widget is for a banner ad in the header. It should be pretty simple. I was just wondering do I need to include the all of the code as posted above and could you tell me what `ci_widgets_init` and `ci_theme` are for?

Comment: The "ci_" bit is the namespace prefix for your theme. An abbreviation if you will. From there ci_widgets_init is the name of the function (which you can rename as desired) and ci_theme is a parameter that tells WordPress where to locate the translation for 'Blog Sidebar'.